# API response on bad resource id

Tags: rest

I've got api controller with route `/resource/{id}` where id is required to be numeric. If request url is `/resource/abc`, then I'll get `404` HTTP response. Is it ok or I should pass any id inside controller, then validate it and response with `400` code?

Comment: Here's a useful [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code) for choosing an appropriate HTTP Status Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the specification you can see that 400 would be the best way to go. [HTTP Status Codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

404 suggests that there currently is no resource with that ID. But since the ID has to be numeric and this is not. That will never change.

400 Says that the syntax is incorrect and more importantly, that the client should not repeat the request without making changes.

Also, keep in mind that you need to include an explanation of the error situation. So the ideal situation would be a 400 status code, telling the client it needs to make changes to the request, and the explanation telling them what changes to make.